# Transfer control to another wpf control during mousedown

Tags: wpf, controls, transfer, mousedown

This time I have a hard one for you :-)

Currently I am about to develop a usercontrol in wpf. I want this control to open up a slider as soon as one presses the mousebutton on a specific button within this control. The user should be able to move this slider as long as the mousebutton is still pressed.

As soon as the user releases the mousebutton the slider should disappear.

I already have a solution for this, but it's a very hacky one, because I am doing it through screen coordinates.

Is there any way to do this in a pleasant way with WPF?

Any help is highly apprechated!

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Please answer these questions first

1. What is your current XAMl and code behind?
2. While pointer of the slider is getting **dragged** along its length, do you want the button to be kept pressed all the time?
3. If so, did you use `ToggleButton` because it can be pressed throughout and can be toggled (unpressed) when you set its `IsChecked` property to false (i.e. when user releases mousebutton).
4. Have you checked mouse button state as `Pressed` (from button event args `e`) when mouse moves, being dragged, over some element such as the slider here?

e.g.

```
    e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed
```

**EDIT**

Related to point no. 2....

The reason why I suggest `ToggleButton` is because only that can be kept pressed while you slide on the slider. Otherwise with normal button, you can open the slider popup on button click but the button will loose its `Pressed` state when you move onto the slider.

Further, the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleButton` can be two way bound to the `IsOpen` property of the slider popup. This way when the user stops sliding and releases the mouse, we can set `IsOpen` of the popup as false and that will automatically **unpress** the togglebutton due to that two way binding.

Comment: Here's a part of what I have for the XAML part so far: 

        <Button Name="SliderButton" />        
        <Popup Name="SliderPopup" IsOpen="{Binding SliderVisible}" />         <Slider  Orientation="Vertical" Name="ValueSlider" />            
        </Popup>

The idea is, that as soon as I click on the "SliderButton" the popup should appear and show the slider control for the user to simply set a value with the mouse.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 2. Yes, because the handling should be as simple as possible. I don't want the user to have to press the mouse button twice.
3. No I did use a normal Button. What would be the advantage of using a toggle button?
4. Do you mean I should use the dragging events for moving the slider?

Comment: Ah ok I see. But the problem is, as long as one keeps the mouse button pressed, I don't get any control over the slider within the popup. Or is there any possibility to recognize that the mouse cursor has moved into the popup and then receive the appropriate events from the slider - even while the mousebutton is still pressed?